# Creating a 'public' group for accessing programs throughout the OS

Tags: 14.04, permissions, android, multi-user

You see, I have xampp, Android SDK installed in /opt/ directory as root.
Now, the problem is, this machine is being used by 2 people (my sister and me) and even she uses them both. The problem arises when she uses Android Studio from her account. She gets these "Permission denied" errors when building the app or debugging it.

My account, on the other hand, has no problem in using Android Studio as the owner of /opt/Android/* is me ( `drwxr-xr-x 10 suryateja suryateja 4096 May 20 23:05 Sdk` ).

Hence, I was thinking of creating a group so as to enable all the users IN THIS GROUP to access all these "Permission denied" type files/directories.

Is this possible? If so, can anyone help me regarding this?
Thank you!

Comment: First, when you installed Android Studio as root, why is `/opt/android/*` not owned by root? Second, users of any program should not be writing to the installation folders. Users should have their own config and data folders for each program under `/home/userid/something`. Your installation is not right. See http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/install-android-studio-ubuntu-14-04-ppa/ for installing android studio properly.

Comment: Well, I did install the SDK as root. But when I started facing issues, I changed the owner to my account.  But in Windows, unless specified, any user can run the programs installed in Program Files right?

Can't we implement that method in Ubuntu?

Comment: Messing with the ownership of folders in `/opt/*` caused the problem. The purpose of installing programs using `sudo` (as root) is so that all users can use them. Always use the Ubuntu Software Center (the first choice) or PPAs (as shown in the link above) to install programs.  This is not Windows, don't download and try to install programs by yourself until you understand the way Ubuntu works better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the comments from @user68186 are totally right and you probably should do it in the right way. But to answer  you:

create a new group

```
sudo groupadd androidStudio
```

Now add your user and your sister user to this group

```
sudo usermod -a -G androidStudio  suryateja
```

do same as above for your sister username.

Now you should change the group ownership of `/opt/Android` to the newly created group

```
sudo chgrp {-R} [group] [file|directory]
```

so for you

```
sudo chgrp -R androidStudio /opt/Android/
```